# Drupal 8 - Add custom HTML with script to embed on a page as block

Tags: 8, forms, blocks, input-formats

I need to add a custom form that has scripts and styles into a page as a block. Its dynamic, so I couldn't attach the scripts (#attached) as libraries. I just need to place the contents as is.

```
$build['test'] = [
  '#markup' => $test_code,
  '#allowed_tags' => [
    'script',
    'style',
    'form',
    'input',
  ],
];
```

I tried it as shown above, but this wasn't working. So, I removed, scripts and style as shown below and that works:

```
$build['test'] = [
  '#markup' => $test_code,
  '#allowed_tags' => [
    'form',
    'input',
  ],
];
```

Any possible solution to render the contents without filtering scripts and style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
$build['test'] = [
  '#children' => $test_code,
];
```